# MCOIMAPFolderInfo and MCOIMAPFolderStatus are giving different messagecounts

Tags: ios, objective-c, imap, mailcore2

I am using the MailCore function `fetchMessagesByNumberOperationWithFolder( MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation)` to fetch the mails from IMAP. I am using `MCOIMAPFolderInfo` to get the folder message count. But it seems to be wrong while checking the emails count in my Gmail folder (when Conversation mode is off).

I tried `MCOIMAPFolderStatus` to get the message count and it was proper. There is a difference of 153 emails between `MCOIMAPFolderInfo` and `MCOIMAPFolderStatus` results, 153 emails less in `MCOIMAPFolderInfo` result.

If I am fetching less than or equal to 153 number of latest emails from the same folder, I am getting zero results and if the count is more than 153, it will fetch the correct number of emails. And this is happening for the accounts were the total number of emails are quite large(for me 12000 emails are there). Why is this happening? Thanks in advance